# How to remove ".x" from column names in the dataframe?

Tags: regex, r

I'm working on a large data set. While using `as.yearmon`to combine values from the same month, I have to use`make.unique(names(df))`to create unique names for each column. From `names(df)`, I can see that `".x",".y",".1",".2"`etc. were added to some of the column names.

I can use `gsub(".x","",names(df),fixed = TRUE)`to remove `".x",".y"`, but the problem is that my column names are numeric like:

```
 name 1.0   1.1   1.2
```

With `".1",".2"`, the column names become:

```
 name 1.0.1   1.1.1   1.2.2
```

If I use `gsub(".1","",names(df),fixed = TRUE)` and `gsub(".2","",names(df),fixed = TRUE)`, the colume names will then become:

```
 name 1.0   1   1
```

My question is that if there is a way to removed the added `".1", ".2"` from the column names without changing the original names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about making sure you're only removing tags at the end of a label?

```
ndf <- c("1.0.1","1.1.1","1.2.2")
gsub("\\.[0-2]$","",‌​ndf)
```